# Custom BERT Classififier in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, bert-language-model, tensorflow-hub

I'm trying to implement a custom classifier exploiting the pretrained BERT model in tensorflow_hub.
I'm facing an issue and I don't know how to solve it.

The code is the following:

```
class BERTClassifier(tf.keras.models.Model):
def __init__(self):
    super(BERTClassifier, self).__init__()
    self.preprocessing_layer = hub.KerasLayer('https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3', name='preprocessing')
    self.encoder = hub.KerasLayer('https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/3', trainable=True, name='BERT_encoder')

def call(self, inputs):
    x = self.preprocessing_layer(inputs)
    x = self.encoder(x)
    x = x['outputs']
    return x


bert_clf = BERTClassifier('small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-8_H-768_A-12', 'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-8_H-768_A-12')
bert_clf.predict(np.array(tf.reshape(["[CLS] Hello world [SEP]"])
```

I expect that the predict method would return the embeddings of the sentence but when I run the code I get the following errors:

```
    ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
      Positional arguments (3 total):
        * Tensor("inputs:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=string)
        * False
        * None
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Expected these arguments to match one of the following 4 option(s):
    
    Option 1:
      Positional arguments (3 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name='sentences')
        * False
        * None
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Option 2:
      Positional arguments (3 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name='sentences')
        * True
        * None
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Option 3:
      Positional arguments (3 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name='inputs')
        * False
        * None
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Option 4:
      Positional arguments (3 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name='inputs')
        * True
        * None
      Keyword arguments: {}
```

What is the problem? How can I solve it?
Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that you're defining `call` but executing `predict`, which is already defined by the keras model you're extending. I had to update your snippet like so:

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow_text
import tensorflow as tf

class BERTClassifier(tf.keras.models.Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(BERTClassifier, self).__init__()
    self.preprocessing_layer = hub.KerasLayer('https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3', name='preprocessing')
    self.encoder = hub.KerasLayer('https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/3', trainable=True, name='BERT_encoder')

  def call(self, inputs):
    x = self.preprocessing_layer(inputs)
    x = self.encoder(x)
    x = x['pooled_output']
    return x

bert_clf = BERTClassifier()
bert_clf.call(tf.constant(["[CLS] Hello world [SEP]"]))
```

Note that the encoder's outputs are stored in `pooled_output` but there is also a `sequence_output` entry. More information on both can be found [on the documentation page of the model](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/3).